# replace NAs in columns with values of new data set (that has identically named columns) in R

Tags: r, na, economics

I have two data sets (data2012 and data2013) that share some identically named rows (ID) and columns (individual characteristics, numerical and metric). Data2012 has values in rows where data2013 has NAs and vice versa.

**I want to replace the NAs in data2012 with the respecitve values from data2013 if the row name (ID) and the column name (individual characteristics) are the same. I only want to replace data2012 with data2013 if data2012 has NAs and data2013 has a value.**

(Since the two data sets have over 200 identically named columns I cannot list every column seperately in the code. Also, the columns do not come in the same order. I need a code that takes advantage of the fact that the columns and rows - where values need to be replaced - have the exact same name.)

**My ideal end-product:** A data set that for every ID (row) has some characteristics (column) from data2012, some from data2013 and some NAs remaining (if both datasets did not have a respective value).

**data2012**

```
     x2  x4  x5  x6  x7  x9
id1  NA  NA  2   NA  4   NA
id2  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  1
id5  NA  3   5   NA  NA  NA
id6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

**data2013** (has extra information in id2 and id6)

```
     x2  x4  x5  x7 
id2  NA  NA  4  NA  
id3  1   NA  2   NA
id4  NA  9   NA  5
id6  1   NA  2   8
```

**ideal end-product**

```
     x2  x4  x5  x6  x7  x9
id1  NA  NA  2   NA  4   NA
id2  1   NA  4   NA  NA  1
id5  NA  3   5   NA  NA  NA
id6  1   NA  2   NA  8   NA
```

I hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

Comment: share the data, instead of describing it.

Comment: edit your question with the output of `dput(head(data2012))` and `dput(head(data2013))` (or at least enough data to reproduce your question)

Comment: Use `match` to match the row names/column names in both datasets along with `is.na` to replace the NA values in one dataset with another.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick responses. I just added some data and hope that makes my question/problem clearer.

Comment: @mtoto: I just added some data, does that help you to help me?

Comment: @Symbolix: I am not entirely sure what you mean but I just added some data; does that make my question/problem clearer?

Comment: @akrun Thank you, I had a look into `match` but don't know how to replace tha value in data2012 without mentioning every single of the over 200 xi variables.

Comment: @Sonha Are these matrices or data.frames?

Comment: @akrun this are two data sets with (rough) dimensions (data2012) 8000 ids x 1000 xis and (data2013) 45000 ids x 200 xis

Comment: My question is whether it is a `data.frame` or `matrix`?

Comment: @akrun it is a `data.frame`

Comment: @Sonha please check the solution below.  I have a doubt.  If there are NA values in the second dataset and the first dataset already have a value for the matching row/column, would you replace that?

Comment: @akrun Thank you; you are right: I only want to replace the value if there is a NA in data2012 and a value in data2013

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot but unfortunately, the solution did not work. I get the following error: `Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i2, j2, value = c("10123701902", "10123706403",  : duplicate subscripts for columns`; also, the number of NAs in data2012 is the same before and after applying the solution (i checked with `sum(is.na(data2012))`

Comment: @Sonha Based on the example you provided, it worked for me.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the column/row indexes of the corresponding datasets, subset the datasets and then assign the values of one to another

```
j1 <- match(colnames(data2012), colnames(data2013), nomatch=0)
j2 <- match(colnames(data2013), colnames(data2012), nomatch=0)
i1 <- match(rownames(data2012), rownames(data2013), nomatch=0)
i2 <- match(rownames(data2013), rownames(data2012), nomatch=0)

m1 <- do.call(pmax, c(list(as.matrix(data2012[i2,j2]), 
        as.matrix(data2013[i1,j1])), list(na.rm=TRUE)))
data2012[i2,j2] <- m1
data2012
#    x2 x4 x5 x6 x7 x9
#id1 NA NA  2 NA  4 NA
#id2  1 NA  4 NA NA  1
#id5 NA  3  5 NA NA NA
#id6  1 NA  2 NA  8 NA
```

#### data

```
data2012 <- structure(list(x2 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA), 
x4 = c(NA, NA, 3L, NA), 
x5 = c(2L, NA, 5L, NA), x6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), x7 = c(4L, 
 NA, NA, NA), x9 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("x2", "x4", 
"x5", "x6", "x7", "x9"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("id1", "id2", "id5", "id6"))

data2013 <- structure(list(x2 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 1L),
 x4 = c(NA, NA, 9L, NA), 
x5 = c(4L, 2L, NA, 2L), x7 = c(NA, NA, 5L, 8L)), .Names = c("x2", 
"x4", "x5", "x7"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("id2", "id3", "id4", "id6"))
```